How to define a global variable in react class?
Hello I have a React project passed down to me from another team member. I need to define a global variable in my React block to later access and modify it's value in my  componentDidMount() and onChangeHandler functions (both are in the same .tsx file, in the same class)
My definitions:
class DataBlock3 extends Component<IProps, Db3stateInterface> {
    let tureValue = null
    constructor(props) {
           ******

class DataBlock3 extends Component<IProps, Db3stateInterface> {
    var tureValue = null
    constructor(props) {
           ******

class DataBlock3 extends Component<IProps, Db3stateInterface> {
    static tureValue = null
    constructor(props) {
           ******

All of these 3 result in my variable being undefined
What is the correct way to define a variable in React?

let and var in that place are syntax errors first and foremost. They should not result in any value.

Do you really mean a global variable? Do you need it to be shared between components?
